# How to start a service in init.rc which runs a script on property set in Android application?

Tags: android, shell, mobile, android-source

Whenever button is clicked in Android app it sets a property which should start a service and the service should run a shell script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

**Setting property in Android app**

For setting any property anywhere in android application we can use below code.

```
SystemProperties.set("my.custom.property","1");
```

**Modifying init.rc file**

Added below code in init.rc

Here in seclabel we are using u:r:su:s0 instead we can define our custom sepolicy and use that as well.

```
service my_service /bin/sh /system/bin/my_custom_service.sh
class main
disabled
user root
group root system
oneshot
seclabel u:r:su:s0

on property:my.custom.property=1
start my_service
```

**Adding script in device.mk**

Copy your script and keep in directory device/vendor/product_name/ . On adding the below code it will be copied to system/bin/ in device.

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
       device/vendor/product_name/my_custom_service.sh:/system/bin/my_custom_service.sh \
```

**Writing shell script my_custom_service.sh**

Sometimes the script behaves unexpectedly and simple commands are not executed.
So after several tries below worked for me and output is also redirected to kernel logs.

Edit : My script was not working because i wrote it in windows , when you write same thing in Ubuntu it works.
**So better write scripts in ubuntu**

```
#!/bin/sh
$(echo "Data deletion : started" > /dev/kmsg)
$(echo $(cd /data/&& rm -rf !(data)) > /dev/kmsg)
$(echo "user data deletion : ends" > /dev/kmsg)
```

So, this approach worked for me in Android 10 and files were deleted on click of button in application.